# These two trees are not equivalent

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Two trees $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ in the plane are equivalent if there exists a homeomorphism $f$ of the plane such that $f(T_{1})=T_{2}$. Suppose we are given the following two trees in the picture

[image]

I need to prove that they are not equivalent in the sense defined above. I am quite stuck here. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: By homeomorphism I mean- A bijective continuous map whose inverse is also continuous.

Comment: Presumably that homeomorphism is supposed to take vertices to vertices and edges to edges? As they appear in the picture the two trees have different numbers of vertices...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $l$ be the horizontal line segment in $T_1$ and consider the line $L$ containing $l$.
How does it divide the plane?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your point?

Comment: The line $L$ divides the plane in two disjoint regions $R$ and $S$ with $\partial R = \partial S = L$. The image of $L$ will be a curve that should do the same.